# Model does not contain a constructor that takes 8 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im am completely new to C# and was trying to setup a very basic application where I created the class/model:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, when I try to instanciate a Customer Object from another class like so:

```
Customer c1 = new Customer(1, "Susan", "Peterson", "Borgergade 45", "8000", "Aarhus", "supe@xmail.dk", "21212121");
```

I get:

> 'PetParadiseHotel.Models.Customer' does not contain a constructor that
>   takes 8 arguments

From my understanding there are exactly 8 arguments that it should take, so what is the problem here?

Comment: Your Customer class has a default constructor(with zero args) since you haven't declared it. Try `new Customer() {CustomerID=1, FirstName="Susan",....};`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to declare them then? How would that look exactly?

Comment: `public Customer(int customerId,....){ this.CustomerID=customerId;... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a contructor for your class

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer(int customerID, string firstName, string lastName, string address,
                    string zipCode, string city, string email, string phone)
    {
        CustomerID = customerID;
        FirstName = firstName;
        // ...
        Phone = phone;
    }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

then call it (like you did)

```
var customer = new Customer(1, "Susan", "Peterson", "Borgergade 45", "8000", "Aarhus", "supe@xmail.dk", "21212121");
```

Or you can use the object initializers:

```
var customer = new Customer() { CustomerID = 1, FirstName = "Susan" ... Phone = "21212121"}
```

Answer (score 2):

C# classes have a default constructor if no explicit constructor is defined. It would look essentially like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
    }

    ...
}
```

In other words, it doesn't do anything, really, and takes no arguments. This allows you to new it up using just the syntax:

```
var customer = new Customer();
```

If you wanted to be able to pass in all those values to the constructor, you would have to create a custom constructor along the lines of:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer(int customerId, string firstName, string lastName, string address, string zipCode, string city, string email, string phone)
    {
        CustomerId = customerId;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Address = address;
        ZipCode = zipCode;
        City = city;
        Email = email;
        Phone = phone;
    }

    ...
}
```

You would also need to redefine the "default" constructor, or you would never be able to just new up an empty `Customer`:

```
public Customer()
{
}
```

Additionally, if you only wanted to pass some subset of those properties, instead of every single one, you would need to create additional constructors for each subset, or provide default values for any not passed in parameters to the constructor. Long and short, this is highly arduous, and makes maintenance a bloody nightmare. Thankfully, C# also has what's called the object initializer syntax. Instead of parenthesis, you use curly brackets and you set each property you want to explicitly:

```
var customer = new Customer
{
    CustomerId = 1,
    FirstName = "Susan",
    LastName = "Peterson",
    ...
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can just keep the default constructor, but still set each property you want to "initialize". Additionally, you can specify whatever subset of properties you want to initialize, so if you don't want to set the `Phone` property, just leave it out. Everything will still work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I've found if there's more than 3, that's a sign to do a quick sanity check on the design. If there's more than 5, that's a major warning that something is probably wrong with the design.

However, note the word "probably" - in the end, the only real rule is use as many as needed to function, no more and no less. There are always exceptions and cases where more parameters makes the most sense.

If the parameters are related somehow, you should encapsulate them into a container class.